# Finding nested result of a certain parent

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following query which works in giving me all periods (nested) +houses  they belong to that have an arrivaldate for the period I specify. 
Now I want to try and get just the arrivaldates for a certain house, but I cannot figure out the syntax of how to do this in Elasticsearch.

```
GET /houses/house/_search
{
  "_source" : ["HouseId"],
 "query": {
 "nested": {
  "path": "Periods",
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"range": {
          "Periods.ArrivalDate": {
          "gte" : "2017-10-01",
          "lt" : "2017-11-01"
         }
        }
       }
     ]
    }
  },
"inner_hits" : {}
}
```

}
}

The mapping is this (shortened to I hope the relevant parts)

```
{
"houses": {
  "mappings": {
     "house": {
        "properties": {
           "Periods": {
              "type": "nested",
              "properties": {
                 "ArrivalDate": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
                 },

 ....
           "HouseId": {
              "type": "keyword"
           },
```

So I would like to find the available arrivaldates for a house with a certain HouseId within a certain month

Comment: You mean something like `"_source": {"include": "Period.ArrivalDate"}` ?

Comment: No I mean to limit the results to just the periods of one house. Your hint is nice to solve my 'inner_hits' 'hack' I think, but not my question. The idea is that for one house I can list the available periods. The query I already have is for searching available houses.

Comment: `inner_hits` and `_source` filtering are two different things. What is a "house"?

Comment: House is the object in which the Periods are located

Comment: You need to provide some more details (maybe the mapping as well), because I don't understand what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have it figured out, but please let me know if better solutions are available:

```
{
"_source":[
  "HouseCode",
  "Country",
  "Region"
],
"query":{
  "bool":{
     "must":[
        {
           "match":{
              "HouseId":"someid"
           }
        },
        {
           "nested":{
              "path":"Periods",
              "query":{
                 "range":{
                    "Periods.ArrivalDate":{
                       "gte":"2017-05-01",
                       "lt":"2017-06-01"
                    }
                 }
              },
              "inner_hits":{
                 "size":1000
              }
           }
        }
     ]
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The query will return you whole houses.

If you wan to get only some Periods, you should use a nested aggregations, combined with a filter aggregation :

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html